# List GitLab repositories that have mirroring enabled

Tags: gitlab, mirroring

We have repository mirroring to Azure set up on quite a few projects in our internal GitLab. I just discovered that generated credentials from Azure Git can be used to mirror other repositories too (not just the ones where the credentials were generated) if you have higher permissions. But I have already setup a lot of projects with different credentials and I would like to use just one pair of credentials and document where they were used. Problem is that now mirroring is set up on some projects and not set up on others.

Is there a way to display all the projects that have some kind of mirroring enabled so I don't have to go trough every single project and check manually?

We are running GitLab14.3.2-ee and I wasn't able to find anything like this in the Admin center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to easily display only repositories with mirroring enabled within the UI. However, you can access this information from the APIs. Calling the list-all-projects API returns a list of projects that you will need to paginate through. Each project has a `mirror` attribute that will be set to true or false, along with info about the mirror URL.

Comment: When I try to list all projects I don't get all the information mentioned in the documentation, I am missing the mirror part of information:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

Could it be caused by the version of our GitLab? On the page it says API is for all tiersso what could I be missing. I am authenticated via a token with all the privileges.

Comment: It's very likely a version question - I just ran a check using the gitlab.com API and the mirror information came back without any issue. It looks like the information was exposed in version 12.6, here is a link to the documentation update adding the mirror info: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/2692b2a24d8b230a7dc543a90c60672b706887c4

Answer (score 1):

using the api this can be done without having gitlab premium (it just slower since you cannot query the mirror property on the project)

Using Powershell

```
# variables
$headers = @{
    Authorization="Bearer [user gitlab token]"
}
$hasPages = $true;
$pageNumber = 1;
$countPerPage = 100; #max value is 100

# keep calling api untill we have loop all pages
while($hasPages) {
    # call get project
    $reponse = Invoke-WebRequest ("https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects?page={0}&per_page={1}&simple=false" -f $pageNumber, $countPerPage) -Headers $headers
    $json = $reponse | Select-Object -Expand Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    # foreach project, get the mirroring details
    foreach ($project in $json) {
        $jsonMirror = Invoke-WebRequest ("https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/{0}/remote_mirrors" -f $project.id) -Headers $headers | Select-Object -Expand Content| ConvertFrom-Json
        # if project has mirroring setup, display it
        if ($jsonMirror.Count -gt 0) {
            Write-Host("{0}" -f $project.name)
            Write-Host(" Repo : {0}" -f $project.web_url)
            Write-Host(" Mirror : {0}" -f $jsonMirror[0].url)
        }
    }
    
    # get the next page number
    $pageNumber = $reponse.Headers["X-Next-Page"]
    # did we reach the last page
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($pageNumber)) {
        $hasPages = $false
    }
}
```

output :

```
Azure DevOps Project Template
 Repo : https://gitlab.company.com/devops-internal/azure-devops-project-template
 Mirror : https://*****:*****@dev.azure.com/DevOpsMacBuilds/Name/_git/Name
Mobile-Lib-Android
 Repo : https://gitlab.company.com/applications/mobile-lib-android
 Mirror : https://*****:*****@dev.azure.com/DevOpsMacBuilds/Mobile-Lib-Android/_git/Mobile-Lib-Android
Mobile-Lib-iOS
 Repo : https://gitlab.company.com/applications/mobile-lib-ios
 Mirror : https://*****:*****@dev.azure.com/DevOpsMacBuilds/Mobile-Lib-iOS/_git/Mobile-Lib-iOS
Install-Android
 Repo : https://gitlab.company.com/applications/install-android
 Mirror : https://*****:*****@dev.azure.com/DevOpsMacBuilds/Install-Android/_git/Install-Android
```

Comment: You might want to add that this is PowerShell code.

Comment: Might be helpful to show what the output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, written in shell.

Requirements:

- jq
- GitLab token set as `PRIVATE_TOKEN`
- GitLab API URL (e.g. https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4) set as `GITLAB_API_URL`

```bash
# Results are paginated; get number of pages
number_of_pages=$(curl -s --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PRIVATE_TOKEN}" "${GITLAB_API_URL}/projects?archived=false" | grep x-total-pages | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r\n')

for page in $(seq 1 $number_of_pages); do
    project_urls=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${PRIVATE_TOKEN}" "${GITLAB_API_URL}/projects?archived=false&page=${page}" | jq -r '.[] | select(.mirror == true) | .web_url')
    if [[ -n "${project_urls}" ]]; then
        echo "${project_urls}" | tr ' ' '\n'
    fi
done
```

Tweak it as needed (e.g. remove `archived=false` if you want to include archived projects)

Comment: Might be helpful to show what the output looks like.